# Get all video URIs from one user on Vimeo via API

Tags: vimeo-api

I'm using the new Vimeo API (which is currently in beta).

I would like to make a request to that API and only get the video URIs for all my videos.
What I can do, is make a GET request to "https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos" (with my authorization). That gives me all the data of all my videos. (See endpoint https://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints/users#/users/+user_id/videos).

Is there a way to limit the response to only a list of the URIs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We actually have a early version of this feature in place right now. It's not yet documented, but feel free to try the "fields" parameter eg: https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos?fields=uri.

This parameter supports the same dot notation that we support across the api, so you can ask for any field you want: eg https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos?fields=pictures.link.